# TMS tilenames for Elliptical Mercator projection - EPSG:3395

Tags: python, openstreetmap, tile-map-service, web-mercator

My goal is to derive TMS tile names from given lat/lon and vice versa for Elliptical Mercator projection (EPSG:3395) using Python.

[OSM wiki explains the logic](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Python) for **Spherical** Mercator (EPSG:3857), but this does not work for **Elliptical** Mercator projection (EPSG:3395).

How do I modify the `deg2num` and `num2deg` logic to appy to latter (EPSG:3395)?

Original fuctions forom OSM wiki are:

```
import math
def deg2num(lat_deg, lon_deg, zoom):
  lat_rad = math.radians(lat_deg)
  n = 2.0 ** zoom
  xtile = int((lon_deg + 180.0) / 360.0 * n)
  ytile = int((1.0 - math.asinh(math.tan(lat_rad)) / math.pi) / 2.0 * n)
  return (xtile, ytile)
```

and

```
import math
def num2deg(xtile, ytile, zoom):
  n = 2.0 ** zoom
  lon_deg = xtile / n * 360.0 - 180.0
  lat_rad = math.atan(math.sinh(math.pi * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))
  lat_deg = math.degrees(lat_rad)
  return (lat_deg, lon_deg)
```

Answer (score 0):

OSM wiki explains the logic for Spherical Mercator (EPSG:3857)

> ytile = n * (1 - (log(tan(lat_rad) + sec(lat_rad)) / π)) / 2

The logic for Spherical Mercator (EPSG:3857)/Elliptical Mercator (EPSG:3395)

(I have studied this article https://habr.com/ru/articles/239251/)

Not the most beautiful solution, but it works

> a = 6378137                       // WGS84 semi-major axis
>
> b = 6356752.3142                  // WGS84 semi-minor axis (EPSG:3395)
>
> e = sqrt(1 - b`**`2 / a`**`2)          // ellipsoid eccentricity
>
> **dy** = 1                            // Spherical Mercator (EPSG:3857)
>
> **dy** = ((1-e`*`sin(lat_rad))/(1+e`*`sin(lat_rad)))`**`(e/2)   // Elliptical Mercator (EPSG:3395)
>
> ytile = n`*`(1 - (log((tan(lat_rad) + sec(lat_rad))`*`**dy**) / π)) / 2